# Get 3 rows with the most recent dates, starting with most recent

Tags: mysql, date

I have this table:

```
  postID | postTitle | date
       1 | example1  | 04/06/2014 ***15:00***
       2 | example2  | 04/06/2014 ***14:00***
       3 | example3  | 04/06/2014 ***14:20***
       3 | example4  | 04/06/2014 ***10:00***
       3 | example5  | 04/06/2014 ***09:00***
```

Current time: 16:00

How can I do three queries where for example query 1 selects the most recent row, query 2 selects the second most recent row and query 3 selects the third most recent row?

Comment: `order by date_column desc limit 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an order desc, and limit

```
select * 
from yourTable
order by `date` desc
limit 3
```

Limit with 1 argument : argument = number of rows.

Limit with 2 argument : first = offset, second = number (offset starting at 0, not 1)

first row

```
limit 1 -- or limit 0, 1
```

second row

```
limit 1, 1
```

third row

```
limit 2, 1
```

Comment: That helps alot thanks mate! Now how can I do three queries where for example query 1 selects the most recent row, query 2 selects the second most recent row and query 3 selects the third most recent row?